# where can i find above iOS path ?

Tags: ios, path

I use the ifunbox to find my this path , but it 's not as what i think it should be.     /var/mobile/Applications/XXX/../../Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist.

Answer (score 0):

You should get this file with the following code

```
NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSString *yourFile = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"com.apple.mobile.installation.plist"];
```

But i'm not sure if you are doing the right thing.